# For each pair of key-values show the values under the key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is an object with this form:

```
anObject = {name_1 : [4], 
            name_2 : [1], 
            name_3 : [5, 1, 2], 
            name_4 : [3, 4],  
};
```

on the left side it is the name of the property and on the right side it is an array of numerical values (one or more values).

I want to show them somehow like this:

```
name_1 
  - 4
name_2
  - 1
name_3 
  - 5
  - 1
name_4
  - 3 
  - 4
```

I can print using an `ng-repeat` the `name_`s like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.anObject ">{{key}}</div>
```

I can show also the numerical values like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.editAlertsByType">{{key}} - {{value}}</div>
```

but I want to put them under the keys. Is it possible?

Comment: `value` is an array, so you need the **second** `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` that you pull out is an array, so display it with the second `ng-repeat`. Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.anObject = {
    name_1: [4],
    name_2: [1],
    name_3: [5, 1, 2],
    name_4: [3, 4],
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in anObject">
    {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="x in value">
      - {{x}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in records">{{key}}
<div >{{value.toString()}}</div>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = {
    "key":[1],
    "key2":[1,2],
    "key3":[1,2,3]
  }
});
</script>
```